# Law of exponent proof

Tags: proof-verification

How can I proof In a two column table that
$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n= \frac{a^n}{b^n}$ given $n$ is any positive integer.

Comment: Try using induction.

Comment: I need it in a two column proof

Comment: I am afraid I have not used said "two column proofs" since geometry back in 8th grade...17 years ago? There should be nothing wrong with demonstrating your reasoning in paragraph form.

Comment: Doesn't Distributive Property for Exponents work. Or have you not learned that?

Comment: Presenting a "two-column" proof merely means justifying or explaining each step, which is  a necessity in any proof, no matter its style. You can write a  proof and then  add spaces so they appear on the left side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the laws of exponents. $(ab)^n=a^nb^n\Rightarrow (a/b)^n=(ab^{-1})^n=a^nb^{-n}=\frac{a^n}{b^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, clearly $(a/b)^1 = a/b = a^1/b^1$ for $n=1$. Now assume that $(a/b)^n = a^n/b^n$ for some positive integer $n$. Then
$$
(a/b)^{n+1} = (a/b)^n(a/b) = a^n/b^n\cdot a/b = a^{n+1}/b^{n+1},
$$
so we conclude by mathematical induction that $(a/b)^n = a^n/b^n$ for all positive integers $n$.